# Elixir - How to include dependencies when making an escript application?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to create a little CLI application in Elixir as a learning project. Parts of this program will require some datetime handling and as such I came upon the Elixir library [Calendar][calendar].

It seems though that it does include the dependencies of [calendar] when I build it with this commands:

```
(mix clean &&)? mix escript.build
```

as it throws me this error:

```
Could not start application tzdata: exited in: Tzdata.App.start(:normal, [])
** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
    ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:shutdown, {:failed_to_start_child, Tzdata.EtsHolder, {%ArgumentError{message: "unknown application: :tzdata"}, [{Application, :app_dir, 1, [file: 'lib/application.ex', line: 428]}, {Application, :app_dir, 2, [file: 'lib/application.ex', line: 437]}, {Tzdata.EtsHolder, :release_dir, 0, [file: 'lib/tzdata/ets_holder.ex', line: 86]}, {Tzdata.EtsHolder, :make_sure_a_release_dir_exists, 0, [file: 'lib/tzdata/ets_holder.ex', line: 70]}, {Tzdata.EtsHolder, :make_sure_a_release_is_on_file, 0, [file: 'lib/tzdata/ets_holder.ex', line: 64]}, {Tzdata.EtsHolder, :init, 1, [file: 'lib/tzdata/ets_holder.ex', line: 10]}, {:gen_server, :init_it, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 328]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 247]}]}}}}
        (tzdata) lib/tzdata/tzdata_app.ex:15: Tzdata.App.start/2
        (kernel) application_master.erl:273: :application_master.start_it_old/4
```

My **mix.exs** is as follows:

```
defmodule Cascli.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :cascli,
     version: "0.1.0",
     elixir: "~> 1.4",
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     escript: escript(),
     deps: deps()]
  end

  def escript do
    [ main_module: Cascli ]
  end

  def application do
    [ extra_applications: [ :logger, :calendar, :tzdata ] ]
  end

  defp deps do
    [
      { :poison,
        "~> 3.0" },
      { :calendar,
        "~> 0.16.1" },
      { :tzdata,      # Tried with and without this dependency
        "~> 0.5.12" } # with no luck.
    ]
  end
end
```

I have Googled and found an [issue][issue-5538] that was solved by [this pull request][pull-5540], but it does not seem to actually solve this particular case. It did however relate to escript building not taking into account dependencies of dependencies. I just don't know whether this is an Elixir issue or an issue with my setup/dependencies. The error is the same even if I try with or without the **:tzdata** entry in the deps and **extra_applications** fields.

It still evades me though as to why it can't find tzdata at all, no matter if I have it as a dependency myself or not.

```
[calendar]:https://github.com/lau/calendar
[pull-5540]:https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/5540
[issue-5538]:https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/5538
```

Comment: Try overriding `tzdata`'s version to `0.1.8`. See https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/issues/86#issuecomment-147517762 for more info.

Comment: @Dogbert Oh my God, this is insane. I wish I had found that a bit earlier. Thank you! If you want to answer the question with an explanation (the fact that versions above **0.1.x** can't run due to being dependent on ETS tables loaded from files. Which you cannot do in escripts, apparently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tzdata` versions after 0.1.x do not currently work with escript as they use `:ets.file2tab` to load a dump into an ETS table, [which doesn't play well with escript archives](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/issues/86#issuecomment-146017452). This is a [known](https://github.com/lau/tzdata/issues/24) [issue](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/issues/86) and the currently recommended solution is to use the `0.1.x` releases of tzdata if you need compatibility with escript. In your deps, you can override the version of `tzdata`:

```
{:tzdata, "~> 0.1", override: true}
```

Comment: This fully answers my question as to why I'm getting the error I am getting when trying to run my escript. I am not sure however that I can revert back due to tzdata not being my dependency directly, but is a dependency of Calendar (I'll have to check this). Accepting the answer though :) Thank you!

Comment: The `override: true` will override the nested dependency so it should work for you.

Comment: I did give it a go yesterday but on a first attempt it didn't work. I didn't have time to see why though, so I'll investigate after work today :)

Comment: Sure, let me know if it doesn't work. I tried it before posting the answer and it worked without the `override` as well.

Comment: Could be something with having to clean my installed deps or something. So I'll see what I can figure out. Thanks again! :)

Comment: It does work, yes. It was just that mix was compiling tzdata as well and that gave me a billion warnings, as well as telling me that the compilation took a long time (where I then cancelled because my laptop was about to die). I was just a rushed and assumed it didn't work, I suppose :) But now the escript is running again. Have yet to actually use Calendar though.